# How to concat as DEPENDS =$(OBJ_$(dir)) in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I am writing a makefile for build which uses multiple dirs. In My makefile I have this

```
1:dir=arch
2:CLEAN_FILES+=$(dir)/*.o
3:include $(dir)/Rules.mk
4:DEPENDS +=$(OBJS_arch)
```

The Rules.mk in arch create a variable called $(OBJS_arch). This logic is applied for all dirs which are peers of arch.

I wish to replace line 4 (which is hardcoded) by $(OBJS_$(dir))

Comment: I have no idea what this question is asking.  Please rephrase it and/or give more detail.

Comment: So, why don't you just write `$(OBJS_$(dir))`?  What about this doesn't behave as expected?

Comment: I did, and thats my q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Make's [join](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-joining-lists-of-words-631) function,

You can try doing as,

```
DEPENDS=$(join OBJ_, $(dir))
```

Make manual says,

```
$(join list1,list2)

Concatenates the two arguments word by word: the two first words (one from each 
argument) concatenated form the first word of the result, the two second words 
form the second word of the result, and so on. So the nth word of the result 
comes from the nth word of each argument. If one argument has more words that the 
other, the extra words are copied unchanged into the result.

For example, ‘$(join a b,.c .o)’ produces ‘a.c b.o’.
```

Comment: can u please put an example

Comment: It works. Do you know How to create an array and a loop in Makefile so that I can pick dir from a list of paths

Comment: Err... what?  Assuming that the variable `dir` contains the value `foo`, then the above example with `join` will expand to `DEPENDS=OBJ_foo`.  I don't see how that in any way relates to your question.  If that's what you want, why bother with `join`?  Just write `DEPENDS=OBJ_$(dir)`.  `join` is only useful if `dir` contains multiple words, like `foo bar biz baz`; then using it you'll get `OBJ_foo OBJ_bar OBJ_biz OBJ_baz` (these exact strings, not the value of the variables named by these strings).

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think I finally understand the problem you're having.  It would be very helpful if you would show the incorrect behavior and describe why it's not what you want.

Anyway.  The issue is you're using a recursive variable `DEPENDS`.  That right-hand side of recursive variables are not expanded until the variable is actually used.  So when you write:

```
dir=one
CLEAN_FILES+=$(dir)/*.o
include $(dir)/Rules.mk
DEPENDS +=$(OBJS_$(dir))

dir=two
CLEAN_FILES+=$(dir)/*.o
include $(dir)/Rules.mk
DEPENDS +=$(OBJS_$(dir))
```

after this depends will have this literal value: `$(OBJS_$(dir)) $(OBJS_$(dir))`.  That value will not be expanded until later.  When it is expanded, `dir` will be whatever the last value was and you'll get multiple copies of the same variable.

You need to use a simply expanded variable, not a recursive variable.  To do this with appending, initialize the variable as simple first, then the append will maintain that:

```
# Make sure DEPENDS is simply expanded
DEPENDS :=

dir=one
CLEAN_FILES+=$(dir)/*.o
include $(dir)/Rules.mk
DEPENDS +=$(OBJS_$(dir))

dir=two
CLEAN_FILES+=$(dir)/*.o
include $(dir)/Rules.mk
DEPENDS +=$(OBJS_$(dir))
```

This will do what you want.

To do it in a loop, since this is makefile commands not shell commands, you'll have to use `eval` which is definitely advanced usage.

Something like this will do it though:

```
DIRS = one two three four

# Make sure DEPENDS is simply expanded
DEPENDS :=

# Define a user-defined macro to include Rules.mk and set DEPENDS
define ADD_DEPENDS
CLEAN_FILES += $1/*.o
include $1/Rules.mk
DEPENDS += $$(OBJS_$1)
endef

# Run it!
$(foreach D,$(DIRS),$(eval $(call ADD_DEPENDS,$D)))
```

Comment: Thanks MadScientist. Can you please help on doing something  like dir_list = one two three . and repeating the clean/include/depends in a loop